# AnchorPane в ScrollPane

Tags: javafx

Добрый день, столкнулся с проблемой размещения компонентов. Вот у Vbox компонентов есть такая вещь как Vgrow(Always), а в ScrollPane её нету, но мне нужно использовать ScrollPane + чтобы в нём компоненты сами растягивались, как от Vgrow у Vbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для растягивания необходимо использовать параметры [setFitToHeight](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#setFitToWidth-boolean-) и [setFitToWidth](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#setFitToWidth-boolean-)

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо!